# Add to Home screen (A2HS) feature detection (no user agent sniffing)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA where Android users are prompted to Add the PWA to their home screen, but I would also like to show a tooltip for Safari users on iOS showing how to add the PWA to their Home screen since it's not a supported feature for them.

I was thinking about using feature detection but I can't find a way to do it, something like:

```js
if ("a2hs" in navigator) {
  // Do something for browsers supporting A2HS feature
} else {
  // Show the tooltip if the browser does not support A2HS
}
```

I also thought I could use something like this:

```
const isIos = () => {
  return window.navigator.vendor === 'Apple Computer, Inc.';
};
```

but this is also returning `true` for users of Chrome on iOS :(

**Any idea how I can detect if a user is using Safari on iOS?**

Note: I also want to [avoid using user agent sniffing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent). I think I read almost all topics related to this subject on SO but so far I couldn't find any solution not using user agent sniffing.

Answer (score 1):

a partial solution:

```js
if('BeforeInstallPromptEvent' in window)
    alert('Chrome-style PWA install experience supported!');
if('standalone' in navigator) // only available on iOS - but also on alternative browsers on iOS without Add-to-Homescreen support
    alert('iOS Safari-style PWA Add-to-Homescreen maybe supported!');
```

Open problems:

- avoid false positives on iOS - if you could accept using the user agent for that, you could use `navigator.userAgent.match(/(iOS|OPT|Brave|GSA|DuckDuckGo|Snapchat)\//)` to detect most alternative browsers; For explanation: iOS in the regex should detect CriOS|FxiOS|EdgiOS|OPiOS (Chrome/Firefox/Edge/Opera mini); Does anbody have a way to detect alternative browsers on iOS without using the user agent?
- it does not detect Firefox on Android; and I don't know if other browsers based on Firefox for Android support PWAs (e.g. QuantMobile, PrivacyWall, Fennec, KAIOS - all tokens that appear together with Firefox and Android in the user agent string)

Addition (untested & unreliable):
I did some more research:

- A sure sign that you are in a webview on iOS is (or was?) that `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` or maybe `navigator.mediaDevices` is undefined. But I also read that Apple implemented it some months ago - so there will be webviews for which this isn't true.
- Another hint might that if `navigator.doNotTrack` is undefined, it could mean that you are in a webview (or that Apple decided to remove this deprecated property from Safari...)

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start :) Maybe using `navigator.buildID` to detect Firefox could work too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/buildID

Comment: @Armel: `navigator.buildID` also detects Firefox Desktop and probably Seamonkey and other Gecko based browsers which don't support PWAs (Firefox Desktop removed experimental behind-a-flag PWA support in version 86)

Comment: Unfortunately `'standalone' in navigator` cannot be used to detect Chrome or Safari on iOS as they both return `true` :(